# Attribute error when updating covariance of scipy.stats.multivariate_normal

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'd like to sequentially update a covariance matrix of a multivariate Gaussian distribution, but getting an AttributeError. Below is a simple piece of code to reproduce the error:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
# Initial mean 
init_pose = np.array([0, 0, 0]).T

# Multi-variate Gaussian 
belief = multivariate_normal(mean=init_pose, cov=np.diag([1e-10, 1e-10, 1e-10])) 
print(belief.mean, belief.cov)

# Update mean and covariance 
belief.mean = np.array([10, 20, 30]).T
belief.cov = np.diag([1, 2, 3])
```

The error messages are:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[42], line 7
      5 print(belief.mean, belief.cov)
      6 belief.mean = np.array([10, 20, 30]).T
----> 7 belief.cov = np.diag([1, 2, 3])
      8 print(belief.mean, belief.cov)

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I checked the attributes of the variable, `belief`, by using `belief.__dict__`, which gives the following:

```
{'_dist': <scipy.stats._multivariate.multivariate_normal_gen object at 0x2b84d81cfc10>,
 'dim': 3, 'mean': array([0., 0., 0.]), 
'cov_object': <scipy.stats._covariance.CovViaPSD object at 0x2b84d81cfbe0>, 
'allow_singular': False, 'maxpts': 3000000, 'abseps': 1e-05, 'releps': 1e-05}
```

As the error suggests, the variable doesn't have `cov` attribute but has `cov_object` instead. Is there any way to update the covariance using a numpy array?

Comment: According to the [source] code, in the `_process_parameters` method, `cov` parameter is processed into a `cov_object`.

Comment: `cov` could be a property, a value that is calculated on the fly, like a method, but without needing ().

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your comments! As a matter of fact, if I compute a new covariance using `stats.Covariance.from_diagonal([1, 2, 3])` and pass it to `belief.cov_object`, I could update the covariance matrix of `belief` variable. However, I don't know how to define a non-diagonal covariance matrix. (Sorry if I'm saying something dumb. I'm a newbie in Python.)

Comment: I found in the source a line that defines `def cov(self)` as a property that returns `return self.cov_object.covariance`.  That in turn is a property itself, something about an explicit representation of the object.

Comment: @hpaulj, So, does that mean a value cannot be set to the covariance in this way because the covariance is a property and not an attribute? If so, is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Look, you have dug into this documenation more than I have.  You already found `stats.Covariance`.  I haven't used this `stats` module myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the covariance matrix is not officially supported in the existing infrastructure. `cov` is a read-only attribute as you can see in the [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/67b2a47ac0dcc909e379b33a733da4d52f92f4fd/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L914-L916). (This is not documented, though, and that is one of many [known issues](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16278) with the multivariate distributions.)

You *can* (although not officially supported) update the `cov_object` attribute you found. If you use `stats.Covariance`, which I'd recommend, this might look like:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal, Covariance

x = [1, 1, 1]

# Initial mean and covariance
init_pose = np.array([0, 0, 0]).T
cov = Covariance.from_diagonal(np.array([1, 2, 3]))

# Multi-variate Gaussian 
belief = multivariate_normal(mean=init_pose, cov=cov) 
belief.pdf(x)  # 0.01036457019516129

# Update covariance
cov = Covariance.from_diagonal(np.array([2, 4, 6]))
belief.cov_object = cov
belief.pdf(x)  # 0.005795060058469202
# same as
# multivariate_normal(mean=init_pose, cov=cov).pdf(x)
```

As long as your new `mean` and `cov_object` don't violate the conditions you can infer from [`_process_parameters_Covariance`](https://github.com/jacopok/scipy/blob/74c7fa075e715aca943aca47b8dbd976fc7e8243/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L421) (basically just consistent dimensionality), I expect it to work correctly. If you change the `mean` and `cov_object` to represent a multivariate normal in a different number of dimensions, you'll also need to update the `dim` attribute accordingly.

---

In the comments, you wrote:

> However, I don't know how to define a non-diagonal covariance matrix.

[`Covariance`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.Covariance.html) has several other options for defining your covariance matrix. The SciPy documentation appears to have certificate issues ATM, but you will find other methods like `from_precision`, `from_cholesky`, and `from_eigendecomposition` that will work for more general covariance matrices.

> So, does that mean a value cannot be set to the covariance in this way because the covariance is a property and not an attribute?

Well, it's because it's a read-only attribute created using the `@property` decoratory; it's not a normal attribute defined in, say, the `__init__` method like `self.cov = cov`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I did notice other methods like `from_precision,` but they are too "fancy" for my purpose. Let's say I want to use `cov = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1]])` for example, how would I define it using `stats.Covariance`. I don't think any of the methods allow us to "explicitly" define the covariance matrix.

Comment: Most calculations involving `multivariate_normal` require some decomposition of the covariance matrix or its inverse. When you provide the covariance matrix directly to `multivariate_normal`, it chooses a decomposition to use automatically, but the default is unnecessary slow to perform and inefficient to work with. `Covariance` allows you to pick the right decomposition for your application. I recommend `from_cholesky` if your matrix is nonsingular. Please follow the example to compute the cholesky decomposition and provide it to `from_cholesky`.